# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed to the remote server

Tags: php, mysql, windows, mysqli, firewall

I  am trying to connect to a remote mysql server, but I get the

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

This connection worked until a few days back, but I suspect an antivirus update changed the permissions for the port. I am unable to figure it out and it's already frustrating.

I am using XAMPP, which I already reinstalled. I have also tried in WAMP, so it is not local webserver related.

Telnet fails when opening connection to host, my IP is allowed on the remote server.

I have also disabled the antivirus and firewall temporarily, but still fail to connect. What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

First check  no other application is using the port. Because of the problem MySQL can't start at the port . check it and is not work means reinstall the xampp with another place like D: , E: , something else.

Comment: Location of the installation shouldn't matter all that much, but rather you've made a valid point about checking if something is using the port, but is MySQL service actually running?

Comment: Yes, the mysql service is running and the other programmers in my team have access to the database. So, the port on the remote server is ok. I am not sure which port xampp is using locally to remote connect. How do I check that?